# Launching a method from a hyperlink in a UIWebView

Tags: objective-c, uiwebview

I am using hyperlinks in a UIWebView object to get around the fact that you can't embed text links into a UIAlertView.

I have identified and created these hyperlinks using the standard 'a href = ...' notation. However, I don't want these links to launch a website - I would like them to launch a method within my app.

How could I redirect a URL click to have it launch a method within my app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement `UIWebViewDelegate`'s [`webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIWebViewDelegate).

Look for `UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked` event, launch a method and return `NO`.

Comment: +1. Also note that you get access to the clicked URL (href) in the delegate method (send `-URL` to the `NSURLRequest` object).

Comment: After 3 hours of trying, I'm going to have to ask for a little more help - I'd like to implement this, but the code is not catching the URL clicks. I've added a method to the class that launches the UIWebView in the first place, but the code never executes when I tap a URL link... I'm using code from: http://inchoo.net/mobile-development/iphone-development/how-to-override-uiwebview-links-request-action-with-your-own-custom-method/

Comment: Have you set `UIWebView` `delegate` to your class object?